# Mount SkyDrive as a network drive

Tags: online-storage, onedrive

[SkyDrive](http://skydrive.live.com/) offers 25GB free space, but only offers a way too simple web upload one file at a time.

Does software exist, that makes it possible to mount it as a network drive?

Edit: The solutions work for a while, but stop working after awhile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use OneDrive as additional backup location](http://superuser.com/questions/835854/use-onedrive-as-additional-backup-location)

Comment: Onedrive did not even exist when I created the question @sunk818, so how can it be a duplicate?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A little update if anyone out there is interested like me :) http://skydrivesimpleviewer.codeplex.com/ gives you WebDAV url's so you can mount Skydrive folders natively in Windows Explorer with "Map network drive".

UPDATE:
In case this method does not work for you (for some users it says invalid username or password), I managed to map skydrive as network drive using MS Word (publish to sky drive and taking url from there).

See Microsoft Office and web section in this document: http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/17/how-to-connect-to-skydrive-with-webdav/

Comment: This is absolutely the way to go.  No third-party software running all the time, and it just works.  This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: That program doesn't works anymore.

Comment: Rather than using the third-party app to get the WebDAV URL, you can also just use Office: open a doc from skydrive in Office, Save As, and see the WebDAV URL right there.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the [Gladinet](http://www.gladinet.com/) software  to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any external tools like Gladinet anymore.

There are a few tutorials:

http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/totw/skydrive.asp

http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/windows-7-map-network-drive-live-skydrive-using-office-2010/

Comment: first link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

**[SkyDrive Explorer](http://skydriveexplorer.com/index.php)** will give you easy access to your SkyDrive from the Windows Explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/) (free and open source FTP, SFTP, WebDAV, etc. browser for Mac, Linux, Windows) has added support for OneDrive. I can confirm it's working on a Mac in version 6+. It's offshoot, Mountain Duck has support for mounting OneDrive folders as local disks.

Answer (score -1):

OneDrive allows you to [mount a network drive natively in Windows via WebDAV](http://web.archive.org/web/20150302165006/http://www.ytechie.com/2014/11/using-unlimited-onedrive-space-for-backups/)

Comment: If you are linking to another answer's content and only providing a link its a sign you should flag the question as a duplicate.  We expect more out of answer than a link a content that (by the way the original source no longer exists) for that exact reason so spend some time and provide the relevant information or I will do it and post my own answer :$

Comment: I see a colon at the end of your answer. Is it truncated?

Comment: I edited the URL so it references web archived version. I don't know about you, but the link I referenced previously worked then and continues to work today. Maybe it was a glitch on your end.